# Sort order of custom meta keys on woocommerce frontend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have made a custom field on my Woocommerce products. It's a numeric value, and it shows perfectly on my product page on my front end via post meta. Then i used this tutorial to put my custom meta key into Woocommerces product sorting dropdown:

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

It works so far that the specific custom meta key can be selected in the drop down, and the right products are shown, but the order of the sorted products is not following the descending order that is given in the code.

```
case 'saetpris':
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'saetpris_pr_maaned';
            $sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $sort_args['order'] = 'DESC';
            break;
```

Rather the order of the products seems to go by product ID.

I have searched a lot on Google and also here on Stack Overflow, but i didn't find any answers. Clearly i am missing something, but what? :-)